# RSpec tests for RestClient::Request.execute: Any way to see the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rest-client

I am using RestClient gem to build an API client and the calls to the API are processed by this method here

```
  def call(api_name,api_endpoint,token = nil,*extra_params)
    endpoint = fetch_endpoint(api_name,api_endpoint)
    params = {}
    endpoint['params'].each_with_index { |p,i| params[p] = endpoint['values'][i] }
    puts params
    if token.nil? then
      response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: endpoint['method'], url: endpoint['url'], params: params.to_json)
    else
      response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: endpoint['method'], url: endpoint['url'], headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"}, params: params.to_json)
    end
    response
  end
```

As you may see, all I do is mounting a hash with parameters/values for the call and invoking `RestClient::Request#execute` to get a response.

It happens that some of my tests, like this one

```
it 'request_autorization' do
  obj = SpotifyIntegration.new
  response = obj.call('spotify','request_authorization',nil,state: obj.random_state_string)
  myjson = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(myjson).to eq({})
end
```

are returning a `400 Bad request` error, and I really don't know why. Other tests, like this one

```
it 'my_playlists (with no authorization token)' do
  obj = SpotifyIntegration.new
  expect {
    response = obj.call('spotify','my_playlists')
  }.to raise_error(RestClient::Unauthorized,'401 Unauthorized')
end
```

processed by the same method, run perfectly fine.

Is there any way to see the request sent? I mean, see how RestClient is mount/sending my request to the corresponding API? May be this way I could understand what is happening.

By "see the request" I mean something like

```
puts RestClient::Request.prepared_request
```

or

```
puts RestClient::Request.prepared_url
```

I've searched the RestClient documentation and found nothing similar, but maybe some of you know how to do this.

Comment: Does `.new` instead of `.execute` give you something you can work with? Just guessing based on the docs [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/RestClient/Request#initialize-instance_method)

Comment: I am going to check. There are some possibilities, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: You might try using `RestClient.log` to get more information, or using WebMock to test that you are seeing web requests generated as you expect.

Comment: I would second using WebMock or something similar to get decent test performance. If you use the `WebMock.disable_net_connect!` option it will show you the request that was made.

Comment: Thanks @MarcRohloff.

Comment: Thanks @alberge. Setting the `RestClient.log` to `stdout` by doing `RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout rspec` did the job and I could see the request. If you post this as an answer I'll be glad in accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using `RestClient.log` to get more information. Something like:

```
RestClient.log = STDOUT
```

WebMock is also a great test framework for HTTP requests. The tests for rest-client itself make a lot of use of WebMock.